# Android Beginner App Development Ideas

Tags: android

I would like to learn Android app which i find more interesting.Please provide simple ideas which can be done to understand the basic operations and to create simple application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here we ask questions regd. problems we face during development. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions to know what kind of questions are accepted here.. :-)

Comment: Sorry buddy this is not the place to get ideas for your development. This is the place to get answers when you get stuck during your development. You can [see](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) here for what type of questions you can ask

Comment: stackoverflow should have something like ideas.stackoverflow.com for questions like this.

Comment: lol. Alright you can close this I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

Though it is not a question that is meant to be answered here. but still as you are a beginner, I would like to give you my opinion. As a beginner, you should try some simple `Activity`, `services`(like music player, `database`(like login form), `Lists`(like gallery and grids views also), `receiver`(receive sms and some other) projects.

Also look in `Android-sdk's` sample folder for some sample projects. There are few projects that could help you in beginning.